# need correct UPDATE statement

Tags: sql

I have two tables like this

`Table 1`:

```
pn          TD
------------------
99sss136    495             
99sss278    495            
99king679   600            
99suu8755   600
```

`Table 2`:

```
pn          Mn
---------------
99sss278     ?
99sss136     ?
99king679    ?
99suu8755    ?
```

In above two tables we can use the inner join using `pn` and `pn`.

I want to update the `Mn` column.

In `table1` 99sss136 & 99sss278 have the same td 495. MN columns should be updated to either 99sss136 or 99sss278

Can you please help?

Comment: Can you try and format your code a bit better for me?

Comment: How should the MN field be updated?

Comment: In your example, what are you expecting the MN values to be?  Can you update that for us?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but here's a couple of suggestions

**First Suggestion**

```
update t2
set mn = t1.td
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1
on t1.pn = t2.pn
```

**Second Suggestion**

```
update t2
set mn = t.pn2
from table2 t2
inner join 
(
    select t1.pn pn1, max(t3.pn) pn2
    from table1 t1
    inner join table1 t3 on t3.td = t1.td
    group by t1.pn
) t 
on t.pn1 = t2.pn
```

Comment: My requirement is mn filed should be updated by 99sss278 either 99sss136. Both of any one

Comment: Not sure I understand - is the second suggestion what you're after?